# How to intercept motionEvents and keyEvents that are generated by user interaction with the UI

Tags: java, android, c, linux, user-interface

I’ve been trying to intercept motionEvents and keyEvents that are generated from the user interaction with the UI. So far I have explored these options:

1. dex injection (too complicated)
2. extended my activity class while intercepting the motionEvents using dispatchTouchEvent logging the event then passing it to super. dispatchTouchEvent(this will require extending all activity classes to my modified class and possibly restrict my application that already uses dispatchTouchEvent)
3. Using instrumentation to add listeners to the application(failed attempt, don’t know if its possible)

Basically what I am trying to do is to implement an event recorder so by capturing motion and keyevents I can create a playback of the recording. One of the restrictions that I have is to be able to attach this recording to any android application therefore I need to minimize the recorders code mofication within the application itself for example I would like to add some jars then initialize them in the application like so:

```
            public class Calculator extends Activity {

            public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

                initialize recorder here
            //application code
            }
            //calculator application code here
            }
```

Note: extending the activity class to a special class which has code that captures the events using dispatchTouchEvent then extending every other activity class from that special class is not a good idea because if the original activity has some code for dispatchTouchEvent then that function wont work in the extended special class.

Solutions from an OS perspective without changing OS code are also welcome(including c, c++)

Answer (score 0):

You mentioned using event listeners, have you read this page?

http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/ui-events.html